# First effective date from a table sql

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table asg_table with columns effective_start_date and effective_end_date.

**asg_table**:

```
asg_number     effective_start_date  effective_end_date   location        department        action_code
1                01-jan-2019           20-jan-2019                        HR                 HIRE     
1                21-JAN-2019           18-FEB-2019         Vietnam        HR                 CHANGE_ASG
1                19-FEB-2019           31-DEC-4712         Vietnam        Manegment          CHANGE_ASG
2                02-mar-2019           29-Apr-2019         Peru           hr                  HIRE
2                30-Apr-2019           31-dec-4712         Vietnam        HR                  CHANGE_ASG
```

I want to create a query to find the first effective_start_date of the employee when the action_code is HIRE, and the location is null.
Is there a function to do so ?

Comment: Do you want to find the first `effective_start_date` for each `asg_number` and then filter to only show those first dates if the `action_code` is `HIRE` and the `location` is `NULL` or do you want to filter by `location` and `action_code` first and then find the first `effective_start_date` for that subset of rows?

Comment: first effective_start_date for each asg_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what order you want to perform the filtering:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE asg_table ( asg_number, effective_start_date, effective_end_date, location, department, action_code ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2019-01-20', NULL,      'HR',         'HIRE'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-21', DATE '2019-02-18', 'Vietnam', 'HR',         'CHANGE_ASG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-02-19', DATE '4712-12-31', 'Vietnam', 'Management', 'CHANGE_ASG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-03-02', DATE '2019-04-29', 'Peru',    'HR',         'HIRE'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-04-30', DATE '2019-05-01', 'Vietnam', 'HR',         'CHANGE_ASG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-05-01', DATE '2019-06-01', 'Vietnam', 'HR',         'FIRE'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-06-01', DATE '4712-12-31', NULL,      'HR',         'HIRE'       FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If you want to filter where `location` is `NULL` and `action_code` is `HIRE` first and then find the earliest `effective_start_date` for each `asg_number` then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY asg_number ORDER BY effective_start_date ASC ) rn
  FROM   asg_table t
  WHERE  location    IS NULL
  AND    action_code = 'HIRE'
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ASG_NUMBER | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | LOCATION | DEPARTMENT | ACTION_CODE | RN
> ---------: | :------------------- | :----------------- | :------- | :--------- | :---------- | -:
>          1 | 2019-01-01           | 2019-01-20         | null     | HR         | HIRE        |  1
>          2 | 2019-06-01           | 4712-12-31         | null     | HR         | HIRE        |  1
> ```

**Query 2**:

If you want to find the earliest `effective_start_date` for each `asg_number` and then filter where `location` is `NULL` and `action_code` is `HIRE` first then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY asg_number ORDER BY effective_start_date ASC ) rn
  FROM   asg_table t
)
WHERE  location    IS NULL
AND    action_code = 'HIRE'
AND    rn = 1
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ASG_NUMBER | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | LOCATION | DEPARTMENT | ACTION_CODE | RN
> ---------: | :------------------- | :----------------- | :------- | :--------- | :---------- | -:
>          1 | 2019-01-01           | 2019-01-20         | null     | HR         | HIRE        |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a520914617b2680afbf0409ce05b395)*

Comment: hi @MT0 this did work.. I had posted a new question. I will be immensely grateful if you could have a look at that too.. I am new to SQL hence a little issue in creating complex queries

Answer (score 0):

No need for function

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE EFFECTIVE_START_DATE IN (CASE WHEN ACTION_CODE='HIRE' AND LOCATION IS NULL THEN EFFECTIVE_START_DATE END)
```

On top of the above query use

```
ROW_NUMBER ANALYTICAL FUNCTION
```

to get the first

```
EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM asg_table WHERE EFFECTIVE_START_DATE IS NOT NULL AND ACTION_CODE='HIRE' AND LOCATION IS NULL;`. I'm not sure that its what the OP intended as it doesn't filter to find the first `effective_start_date`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is some column to identify the employee.

Try this:

```
Select * from
  (Select t.*, 
  Row_number() over 
  (partition by t.employee_id order by t.effective_start_date) as rn
  From asg_table t
  Where t.location is null 
  AND t.action_code = 'HIRE')
Where rn = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: You probably want `PARTITION BY t.asg_number` rather than `PARTITION BY t.employee_id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(effective_start_date) OVER(PARTITION BY action_code ORDER BY action_code) AS first_effective_start_date,A.*
FROM asg_table A
WHERE LOCATION  IS NULL
AND action_code ='HIRE'
;
```

If you would like to get all records along with first_effective_start_date as a separate column.

Cheers!!

Comment: Should this not be `PARTITION BY asg_number` rather than `PARTITION BY action_code`?

Comment: The requirement was to get the first effective_start_date by action_code hence my approach was to partition the records based on action_code.

Comment: But the `action_code` is always going to be `HIRE` so you are going to `PARTITION BY` the entire data set and will get the first `effective_start_date` of all the users rather than the first `effective_start_date` for each user.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT MIN(effective_start_date) FROM asg_table) as first 
FROM 
    asg_table 
WHERE 
    location IS NULL AND action_code = "HIRE" 
LIMIT 1;
```

Enjoy!

Comment: `LIMIT` ? I don't think that this is valid in oracle.

Comment: The sub-select will return the min date from entire table without any condition.